# Use the standard google maps interface on embedded maps / google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This surely sounds like a silly question in my head, but I want to put it out there nonetheless just to make sure I haven't missed anything.

I've got a page on my website that has a google map (currently 'embedded' through the google maps api v3).
While I'm perfectly capable of interacting with that map through a custom form (and the google map api):

```
an input box to set starting point
an input box to set endpoint
a dropdown list for transportation modes
```

I was wondering if it was possible (in comes the silliness) to use google's own interface for this (cause users are used to this).

Abstracting my question: Is there a way to "bring in" Google Maps' own UI on an embedded map and do some calculations on my own page, based on the routes (/modes of transportations, etc) that are being selected in that UI.

My guess: no. The google maps UI is something that can only show up on maps embedded with an iFrame (so only on maps.google.com) and no interaction with it is possible, at least not in a kosher way.

[image: Short overview of what I want to achieve]

Answer (score 1):

There is the direction API which you can use to obtain responses (JSON or XML) regarding useful information such as distance, start coordinate, travel mode, etc. You can interact with the response to obtain what is needed for your web page.

I have posted a link for the direction API. Hope this can help.

[Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but the introduction of the Directions API doesn't sound all to promising (regarding user interaction) : "This service is generally designed for calculating directions for static (known in advance) addresses for placement of application content on a map; this service is not designed to respond in real time to user input, for example. For dynamic directions calculations"